# $X\sim B(n,p)$,compute P{have m times failure before the n-th success}

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I met a question:

in a Bernoulli experiment, the probability of success is p, compute the probability that have m times failure before the n-th success?

the answer is 
$$C_{n+m-1}^{n-1}p^{n-1}(1-p)^m\cdot p $$

but my answer is 
$$P\{\text{fail m times in the previous m+n-1 times }|\text{the n+m -th  succeed}\} = \frac{C_{n+m-1}^{n-1}p^{n-1}(1-p)^m \cdot p}{p}= C_{n+m-1}^{n-1}p^{n-1}(1-p)^m $$
cuz, I think this is a conditional probability

what is the exact answer of this question? if I'm wrong, I wonder, for what kind of question, its correct answer is mine.

Comment: Let $X_i$ be the number of successes ($0$ or $1$) on the $i$-th trial, and let $S_i$ be the total number of successes in the first $i$ trials. The problem asks for $P(\{S_{m+n}=n\} \cap \{X_{m+n}=1\})$, whereas your answer is the conditional probability $P(\{S_{m+n}=n\} \mid \{X_{m+n}=1\}).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the solution. Let $F_1,...,F_m$ the $m$ failure and $S_1,...,S_{n}$ the success. Look at  $$\underbrace{\{F_1,...,F_m,S_1,...,S_{n-1}\}}_{=A}\cup\{S_n\}.$$
All "permutation" of $A$ is correct, and thus you'll get $$\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}(1-p)^mp^{n-1}=\binom{n+m-1}{m}(1-p)^mp^{n-1}$$

for all path of type $\{F_1,...,F_m,S_1,...,S_{n-1}\}$. But to finish, you need a success, and thus multiply by $p$. At the end, you'll get 
$$\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}(1-p)^mp^{n-1}p=\binom{n+m-1}{m}(1-p)^mp^{n-1}p,$$
as your solution suggested.

Comment: thank you, a further ask. for what kind of question, I don't need to consider the final success. maybe eg: if the question is, the n+m -th experiment is successful, compute the probability that fail m times, in the former m+n-1 times experiment?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand the question. The question is more or less "make $m$ failure and $n$ success, but finish with a success".@SGVU

Comment: I think I get your idea. for the question -- make m failure and n success, but finish with a success. does it also need to multiple p in the end, which means the final experiment is successful,

Comment: Yes of course ! Make a tree and you'll see @SGVU